# List comprehension not giving expected result

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, with each tuple containing a tuple pair, coordinates.

```py
list1 = [((11, 11), (12, 12)), ((21, 21), (22, 22)), ((31, 31), (32, 32))]
```

Using list comprehension I am trying to generate a list without them being paired but still in the same order.
I was able to get the result be looping and using `.append()` but I was trying to avoid this.

```py
new_list = []
for i in list1:
    for x in i:
        new_list.append(x)

print(new_list)
```

this works and gives me the result I am looking for:

```
[(11, 11), (12, 12), (21, 21), (22, 22), (31, 31), (32, 32)]
```

But when I try list comprehension I get the last tuple pair repeated!

```py
new_list = [x for x in i for i in list1]
print(new_list)
```

```
[(31, 31), (31, 31), (31, 31), (32, 32), (32, 32), (32, 32)]
```

I am sure it is a small thing I am doing wrong so would appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 2):

try :

```py
print([inner_tuple for outer_tuple in list1 for inner_tuple in outer_tuple])
```

Nested `for`s should come to the right side. `for sub in list1` after that `for x in sub`.

And btw, you didn't get `NameError: name 'i' is not defined` because, you wrote that list-comprehension after the for loop. In that time `i` is a global variable and exists.

Answer (score 1):

The execution of the loop is out-inner type
Your code misses is close but it takes `x` only

- Your code:

```py
new_list = []
for i in list1:
    for x in i:
        new_list.append(x)
```

- which is equivalent to

```py
new_list = [x for i in list1 for x in i]
```

So, now you can understand the variables how they are taking values from `for` loops