# Flatten list of tuples containing tuples

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, with each tuple containing a tuple pair, coordinates.

```
list1 = [((11, 11), (12, 12)), ((21, 21), (22, 22)), ((31,31), (32,32))] # list of tuple pairs
```

Using list comprehension I am trying to generate a list without them being paired but still in the same order. I was able to get the result be looping and using `.append()` but I was trying to avoid this.

```
new_list = []
for i in list1:
    for x in i:
        new_list.append(x)

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[(11, 11), (12, 12), (21, 21), (22, 22), (31, 31), (32, 32)]
```

this works and gives me the result I am looking for:

But when I try list comprehension I get the last tuple pair repeated!

```
new_list = [x for x in i for i in list1]

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[(31, 31), (31, 31), (31, 31), (32, 32), (32, 32), (32, 32)]
```

I am sure it is a small thing I am doing wrong so would appreciate the help!!

Comment: `[t for vals in list1 for t in vals]` should give the expected output. Read more about [Nested for loop list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: Could discard the last element: `new_list = [x for x in i for i in list1][:-1]`

Comment: Didn't you ask this question 1 hour ago today ?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/70997748/13944524

Comment: The left-to-right ordering of generators in a list comprehension should match the top-to-bottom ordering of iterators in a nested for loop.

Comment: That is, write your for loops on one line then move the body of the inner loop to the front of the expression, drop the `:`s, wrap it all in `[...]`, and call it a day.

Comment: Yea, posted this an hour previous but thought I messed up on formating the post to show the code properly so deleted I thought! and reposted properly!!

Answer (score 2):

Python is having inbuilt function [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to achieve the same result:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [((11, 11), (12, 12)), ((21, 21), (22, 22)), ((31,31), (32,32))]


>>> list(chain.from_iterable(my_list))  # OR, list(chain(*my_list))
[(11, 11), (12, 12), (21, 21), (22, 22), (31, 31), (32, 32)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Alex Martelli's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/298607) to flatten a list of lists by one level:

```
>>> [t for tt in list1 for t in tt]
[(11, 11), (12, 12), (21, 21), (22, 22), (31, 31), (32, 32)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the expected output:

```
flat_list1 = [result_tuple for coupled_tuples in list1 for result_tuple in coupled_tuples]
```

Like in your question - where you looped over `list1` and then each of it's tuple elements, `for coupled_tuples in list1` is the outer loop, `for result_tuple in coupled_tuples` is the inner loop.

You can have as many independent `for x in y` clauses as you want in a comprehension just by sticking one after the other.

```
flat_list1 = [
              result_tuple                       # result
              for coupled_tuples in list1        # outer for loop
              for result_tuple in coupled_tuples # inner for loop
             ]
```